# Can NB model cope with excess # zeros

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I have a counts response variable with 46% of the observations being zeros, and am validating model fits to different distributions with GAMMs. I have plotted the observed number of zeros in the response against # zero from 10000 simulated datasets for both Poisson & NB distributions to see if either can cope with the excess zeros.

My question is:

Can the NB model in this case cope with the excess number of zeros in my response, considering that the observed # zeros falls on the tail of the simulated distribution? In other words, how close to the middle of the histogram must the observed # zeros fall to confidently say that the model can account for the excess zeros in the response?

**Poisson model**
[image: Dispersion statistic vs. simulated datasets under Poisson model]
**Negative Binomial model**
[image: Dispersion statistic vs. simulated datasets under NB model]

Comment: What is your data? What are those zeros? Won't zero-inflated models work for this data?

Comment: My data is annual bird counts from different monitoring sites over several years. Zeros are absences, and yes ZI model would presumably work (if necessary), but I can't tell if it's necessary here.

Comment: Could you tell us more about this data? For example, I guess that birds migrate, so for example during a winter season some birds are not seen at all, in such a case zero-inflation for the winter makes a lot of sense (if even the winter season should not be excluded from the data).

Comment: The bird species in this case is migratory, and the counts are from the breeding grounds where the bird spends half the year (Mar-Aug). The "annual counts" that I am modelling are from standardized observations across each monitoring site during the breeding season.

Comment: NB can't cope with excess 0s - but it can generate 0s and it will generate as many or more than a Poisson with the same rate mean. You should be asking if the data have more 0s than are estimated by the model (i.e. more zeroes than the estimated conditional distribution of the response). A rootogram or posterior predictive check (simulate many new data sets as large as the observed data from the model, and for each simulated data set count the number of zeros. Draw a histogram of the number of 0s in the simulated data sets and see where the obs # 0s lies.) would help with that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - in fact, the plots above show just what you suggest (observed # zeros in response variable vs. # zeros in 10000 simulations from each distribution). I mistakenly described them as displaying the dispersion statistic, so I have edited the question accordingly and apologies for that. With this clarification, does the NB plot indicate that ZI model is required?

Comment: You need to simulate new data *from the model*, not from the *distribution*; which did you do? Excess 0s are a function of the data relative to the model, not a distribution. If those are #s in each of 10,000 data sets simulated from a fitted NB model and a fitted Poisson model, then I'd say your model is wrong (missing covariates that might predict a low lambda (mean)?). You might not be able to fix this wrongness, in which case a zero-inflated model might help

Comment: Apologies for my incorrect terminology - I'm quite novice at this as you can tell. I simulated new data from the model (i.e. YSim = simulate(m1, 10000)) where m1 is the global model, then specified a function (MyZeros <- function(x){sum(x==0)}) to calculate the # zeros, and applied it to each column in YSim (Zeros <- apply(YSim, MARGIN = 2, FUN = MyZeros) and plotted # simulated zeros in the histograms above.

Comment: Cool; so ideally, you would want the red dot to be roughly in the middle of the histogram of zeros. You want your observed data to look like a typical simulated data set, generated from your model. In that case, your model is a good approximation of the data generating process. In your case, however, your Poisson model is a terrible candidate for the data generating mechanism, and the NegBin model is a poor candidate for the data generating mechanism. Your data exhibits many more zeroes that typically expected given the model.

Comment: Assuming you've exhausted the covariates available, you could proceed by fitting a Zero-inflated or Zero-altered Negative Binomial model, and use your covariates to model the zero-inflation/augmentation as well as the usual NegBin parameters. That's not easy for GAMMs; I think the gamlss  can do this, as can the brms 

Comment: Thank you for these insights - what is the benefit/purpose of adding covariates to the zero-inflation argument as opposed to intercept-only?